# Why does unit test try to find other beans in a controller specific unit test in spring boot

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mocking

I want to test a single controller which has dependency on 1 service and 1 repo using @WebMvcTest annotation. There are other 5 services/repo in the whole app which i wouldn't want to mock in this unit test.

I have mocked the required 2 services/repo. Here i am testing a simple endpoint which doesn't even access the repo but when i try to unit test this controller for that specific controller in spring boot like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(WebController.class)
public class LoginTest {

@MockBean 
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@MockBean 
private CustomerService customerService;

private MockMvc mockMvc;


@Test
    public void serverRunning() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string("Server is running"))
        .andDo(print());
    }

}
```

I get

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantRequestRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#60b4d934' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#60b4d934': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available`

Note: If i use @SpringBootTest, it works but i don't want to instantiate the whole application for a simple test.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into exactly the same problem. This was caused by having the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on my main Spring app class. The webmvc test disables full auto-configuration, but must still load the base application class.

Easy fix, fortunately, simply create a new configuration class and move your `@EnableXRepository` annotations to that class instead, and they won't be included in your webmvc test!

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
class PersistenceConfiguration {}
```